# dotnetnuke html module fails to load file uploaders when installed with pageblaster

Tags: caching, dotnetnuke

site on dotnetnuke 5.06.03 is not loading file uploaders (image file uploader, flash file uploader etc.) after snapsis pageblaster 3.6.1 is installed. file uploaders works great when pageblaster is disabled.

Answer (score 1):

I am no longer a fan of the PageBlaster module in the v5.x and v6.x series of releases. In fact, I find that in the recent versions of DotNetNuke, it just gets in the way (as you've found).  That being said, you should be able to add exclude rules to prevent PageBlaster from corrupting your editor.  The exact rules will depend on your implementation.  You can use tools like [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) and the PageBlaster trace file to help you determine the rules you need.

Comment: I agree with you about PageBlaster.

Comment: I still find PageBlaster invaluable on DNN 5.6.3